# Don't send me to meta-review just for fun

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design, user-interface

When being at the Reviews list on Stack Overflow, at the bottom of the page, I'm presented with: 'Meta Reviews'.

My reputation isn't enough to review any content on meta, so I think that link makes no sense there for my particular case.

Comment: Good idea only to ask people to look at the meta-queues when they can actually do so.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on the Stack Exchange meta?

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be too hard to check if a user has enough rep to review on Meta, and hide the link if not.
There will already be user data checks on that page to know which Review tasks to show us.

Although, I'm not convinced spending developer time is ideal on such a *trivial* issue. Given the plethora of functions and other actual issues/potential improvements around the site, I'd rather time was spent on more useful functionality.

Also, it's at the bottom of the page, so just ignore it :)

And then when you *do* have enough reputation points, you'll remember and can come to Meta and do some reviews.

Comment: I'll need to wait until I get 2.000 :-(

Comment: Ah, so it's a feature not a pointless indirection?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Not a clue. Stack might be happy to implement this. I couldn't answer that as I do not work in their dev team so no idea of their work load, how much time this would take up, or even their motives. Perhaps they want it there to *remind* everyone. I doubt it as Meta review queues are usually empty. I was just answering to say I think it's barely a problem, and I'm happy ignoring it and would favour dev time spent on other things.

Comment: @alexandresaiz, as someone who recently hit 2k and tried out meta review, no, you'll need to wait until you get 3000. Suggested Edits is a no-op. (Why it's still enabled I do not know.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Suggested Edits exist on meta sites because of tag wikis. Users can suggest edits to those, and others can review them -- however, the latter requires 5k.

Comment: @pizza: So then why do I have access to a queue that is perpetually and by design empty for another 3k? These things are mysteries.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It is the ineffable will of Shog.

Comment: Peter Mortensen/bjb568 - Can you two not have an edit competition on my answer :P